# Issue with using the same template for different states on ui-router

Tags: angularjs, routes, angular-ui-router, angularjs-routing

I'm trying to use the same template for 2 different views. My set up is this

```
$stateProvider.state('me', { 
    url: '/me', 
    templateUrl: 'partial/profile/profile.html',
    controller: 'ProfileController'
  });

  $stateProvider.state('myteam', { 
    url: '/myteam', 
    templateUrl: 'partial/myteam/myteam.html',
    controller: 'MyteamController' 
  });


  $stateProvider.state('myteam.teamMember', { 
    url: '/:username', 
    templateUrl: 'partial/profile/profile.html',
    controller: 'ProfileController'
  });
```

However whenever I try and access **myteam.teamMember**, the URL changes but the view doesn't change. Anyone have any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you redirect to `child` state it looks for `ui-view`(it can be named view) on current state HTML, and load the state template in it. Basically you are redirecting to child state of `myteam`, so to get the changes on view you should have `ui-view` somewhere inside `partial/myteam/myteam.html` HTML file.

**partial/myteam/myteam.html**

```
<div>
 MY HTML

 ......

 .......

 <div ui-view></div>

</div>
```

Comment: @Dave Pleased it helped, Thanks :)